# Displaying Category Articles in Joomla Home page

Tags: php, templates, joomla

I am wondering about displaying categories in home page.

I have 5 different categories under 1 section. And All categories have as many articles as they have.

Now I want to show the category title and its few articles in home page...

I am not sure about which module or component to use OR can we do it self?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched the sites and finally **mod_junewsultra** module build for making newsflash has been useful. Hope it can make u 2 easy..